# change div position - div behind another div

Tags: html

I have a navigation div which is fixed and 10% transparent - this div is locate on the top of my web page. I create another div that I want it to be in the bottom of the first div. When I ran the code the second div starts in the top of my web page and because of my transparent div i can see the second one.

I know there is an option to set up the second div top position as px, but i  hope there is another and simpler way to do so (especially because I plan to add another div after the second one).

That is my HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="nav_bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main_pics">
<!-- photos here -->

</div>
```

that's my css code:

```
#nav_bar{
border: 2px solid black;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.98);
height: 55px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: -2px;
}
#main_pics{
width: 80%;
background-color: gray;
height: 500px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the discussion between you and maioman, couldn't really understand what do you mean by the simple way.

The first approach (same as what maioman suggested): http://jsfiddle.net/u6eydqw8/
the subsequent div addedd after the `main_pics` do not need to put any `*-top` anymore..

the second approach, add an invisible container which has the same height (including the border width) to the DOM, then you do not need to adjust the `*-top`. can see here http://jsfiddle.net/u6eydqw8/1/

please comment if this is what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

add `position:fixed ; top:0;` to `#nav-bar` css properties

and `display:block ; margin-top:60px // (or the size you need ...)` to #main-pics

Comment: but as i said, it's position is fixed

Comment: i know that the simple answer is to add margin-top, but I asked for a simple way, mainly because I want to add more divs and i don't want to calculate the top with every div that I add. just read what i asked for...

Comment: ok , there are many solutions and you need to try what's better    in your scenario but the simplest answer could be to wrap all the following contents (for. ex #main-pics , #main-pics2 , ...,#footer) in a wrapper with either a margin or padding top